# Can two android devices in different network(3g) comunicate themselves with ssh connection?

Tags: ssh, c, android, icmp

I have two rooted android devices with different isp (I use different 3g connection for them) and created a double ssh connection (I can with a public ip server) communicating both to this server (I have installed connectbot and proxydroid on two devices).

I want to echo request a device from the other and receive the echo reply to first device, both connected to ssh server yet, to calculate timestamp of icmp packets (I use c4droid to run c program in both device).

I want to know: how can I do this? Do I have to modify some iptables android rules or do I have to do else?

Comment: You probably just need to write a small daemon and client program which would distribute your message to other clients on the server that you run in each session.